# How to install an custom ROM for android car head unit?

Tags: custom-roms, rom, automotive-head-unit

I'm trying to install a custom rom on my Lenovo D1 head unit but since it doesn't have physical buttons i'm struggling to get my device in to recovery mode.

The reason I'm trying this is my device is very slow sometime so i thought i should try a lightweight ROM, no specific one yet but im gonna try multiple ones.

Anyone know how can i achieve this?
Thanks